# MATLAB massive multi-assignment technique

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to assign ~1 Million values to a 100x100 logical matrix like this:

```
CC(Labels,LabelsXplusOne) = true;
```

where CC is 100x100 logical and Labels, LabelsXplusOne are 1024x768 int32.

The problem now is the above statement takes about as long as 5 minutes to complete on a modern CPU. 
Obviously it is badly implemented in MATLAB, so how can we make the above run faster without resorting to loops?

In case you are wondering, i need this statement to compute blobs in a integer (not binary) image.

And also:

```
max(max(Labels)) = 100
max(max(LabelsXplusOne)) = 100
```

EDIT:
Ok i got it. Maybe this will help others in the future:

```
tic; CC(sub2ind(size(CC),Labels,LabelsXplusOne)) = true; toc;
Elapsed time is 0.026414 seconds.
```

Much better now.

Comment: From what I've learned during my time with MATLAB, trying to beat its implementation is a losing fight. What you *can* do is rethink the problem in such a way that the statement is not needed or reduced in scope. As such, I understand you've given a general problem statement, but a little more detail regarding the problem at hand/surrounding code would probably help others help you

Comment: also there are little to no examples that come to mind of core matlab functions that are *badly* implemented - in fact they are highly optimized for exactly the type of work you're doing here

Comment: Basically i need a function like 'bwlabel' which works with integer images, not binary.

Comment: regarding your 2nd comment: doing the above in C/C++ will probably run in a few milliseconds. It's just a few million integer operations.

Comment: good call on vectorizing your matrix, that's a great trick that is underused (esp by me!)

Comment: I didn't see that you already found your mistake before I posted my answer. However, I gave a little more explanation and an additional tweak that may speed things up further for you.

Comment: @AK4749 Of course I don't know what exactly you mean by 'core matlab functions', but in my experience it is very very often beneficial performance-wise to rethink what matlab does. Not to talk too much about it, [things like the lightning toolbox](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/minka/software/lightspeed/) exist for a reason.

Comment: @angainor After looking at your link, I think it doesn't deter me from saying the core functions (ie the base operators such as indexing, max function, etc that @user was attempting) are very tight. However, I was very surprised to find `repmat` in that toolbox you provided. Extremely interesting, and you can be sure I'll look a little harder when I next try to optimize matlab, thank you!

Comment: @AK4749 thats why I asked about *core functionality*. More examples, if you deal with sparse matrices, you may want to look at SuiteSparse by Tim Davis. `sparse2` function, just to name one function in the package, is much faster than MATLABs.

Comment: @AK4749 Have a look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382155/is-indexing-vectors-in-matlab-inefficient) - it deals with the inefficiency of vector (and likely matrix) indexing in MATLAB. I think there is a lot of things you can do better (performance-wise) than MATLAB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues that jump out at me...

1. I have the feeling you are doing the [matrix indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) wrong. As it stands now, what will happen is *every* value in `Labels` will be paired with *every* value in `LabelsXplusOne`, producing (1024*768)^2 total index pairs for your rows and columns of `CC`. That's likely what's taking so long.

   What you *probably* want is to only use each pair of values as indices, like `Labels(1,1),LabelsXplusOne(1,1)`, `Labels(1,2),LabelsXplusOne(1,2)`, etc. To do this, you should convert your indices into [linear indices](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511) using the function [SUB2IND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html).
2. Additionally, your matrix `CC` only contains 10,000 entries, yet your index matrices each contain 786,432 integer values. This means you will end up assigning the value `true` to the same entry in `CC` *many* times over. You should first remove redundant sets of indices using the function [UNIQUE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html), *then* use them to assign values to `CC`.

This is what I think you want:

```
CC(unique(sub2ind(size(CC), Labels, LabelsXplusOne))) = true;
```

Comment: Oh yeah, i forgot. You're right it was a (1024*768)^2 assignment, that explains a lot. Using sub2ind did the trick. Although i think using unique will be slower than doing multiple assignements, since it has to sort the values.