# How to sum all other rows in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, sum

I am still learning some of the advanced features in MATLAB.

I have a 2D matrix and I want to sum all rows, except for for i.

eg

```
1 1 1
2 2 2
4 4 4
```

say i = 2, I want to get this:

```
5 5 5
```

I can do it by summing all the rows, then subtracting row i, but I want to know if there is a faster way using MATLAB's indexing/selection syntax.

Answer (score 7):

It seems that  summing all the rows, then subtracting row i, is much faster tough:

```
A=rand(500);
n = randi(500);
tic
for i=1:1e3
%sum(A([1:n-1 n+1:end], :));
sum(A)-A(n,:);
end
toc

     Elapsed time is 0.162987 seconds.

A=rand(500);
n = randi(500);
tic
for i=1:1e3
sum(A([1:n-1 n+1:end], :));
end
toc

     Elapsed time is 1.386113 seconds.
```

Comment: You have a rather fast computer, nate. What are you using? I have an i7 2.8GHz, and my results are 4 times slower than yours.. That worries me :)

Answer (score 4):

To add to the performance considerations of previous authors. The solution by nate is faster, because it does not use complex matrix indexing of the second method. Complex matrix/vector indexing [is very inefficient in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382155/is-indexing-vectors-in-matlab-inefficient). I suspect this is the same problem with indexing as the one described in the cited question.

Consider the following simple tests, following the previous framework:

```
A=rand(500);
n = randi(500);
tic
for i=1:1e3
    B=sum(A(:, :));
end
toc
Elapsed time is 0.747704 seconds.

tic
for i=1:1e3
    B=sum(A(1:end, :));
end
toc
Elapsed time is 5.476109 seconds.   % What ???!!!

tic
id = [1:n-1 n+1:500];
for i=1:1e3
    B=sum(A(id, :));
end
toc
Elapsed time is 5.449064 seconds.
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could do it like this:

```
>> A = [ 1 1 1
         2 2 2
         4 4 4];
>> n = 2;
>> sum(A([1:n-1 n+1:end], :))
ans = 
    5 5 5
```

However, as Nate has already indicated, as nice as it may look, it's actually so much slower than just subtracting a single row that I advise against using it :)

Comment: @nate: hmmm...now why would it be *SO* much slower? It's a order-of-magnitude, even if you unloop the creation of the indices...

Comment: It is slow because of inefficient indexing in MATLAB :)

Comment: @angainor: Yes, I saw your question/analysis the other day...have you submitted a performance bug to TMW? The slowness seems completely unneccessary...

Comment: I have [reposted the question](http://www.mathworks.se/matlabcentral/answers/54522-why-is-indexing-vectors-matrices-in-matlab-very-inefficient) at matlab central. Hope someone from TMW will care to answer.