# forcing limits on a vector in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a problem : 
suppose I have a matrix

```
A =

    -1     2    -3
    -4     5    -6
    -7     8    -9
```

I convert it into a column matrix

```
B = A(:)

B =

    -1
    -4
    -7
     2
     5
     8
    -3
    -6
    -9
```

Suppose I want to force the first column elements to lie within a particular range (-range1 : range1) , second column elements within (-range2 : range2) & third column elements within (-range3:range3). I tried doing that by implementing this code :

```
range1 = 0;
range2 = -5;
range3 = 0;

B(B(1:3,1)<range1)=10;
B(B(4:6,1)>range2)=0;
B(B(7:9,1)<range3)=20;
```

The answer I get is this :

```
B =

    20
    20
    20
     2
     5
     8
    -3
    -6
    -9
```

Whereas the correct answer I should get is this :

```
B =

    10
    10
    10
     0
     0
     0
    20
    20
    20
```

What I am doing wrong ? Please help.

Comment: Please check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18201729/forcing-the-columns-of-a-matrix-within-different-limits/18201856#18201856. It's a continuation of this question.

Comment: Are you sure if your actual B output is correct? with the conditions you have mentioned

Comment: sorry I corrected the answer that I expect. Please check my edited question.

Comment: Your expected outcome does not match the description of the problem at all. For example, `10` is not in the range of `-0:0`

Comment: I made a mistake. Should not have termed it as range. Please recheck my code! If the particular no's is greater than the no range1 or less than range1 then I am forcing it to 10 (a particular value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What is wrong:

Look closely at your command:

```
>> B( B(7:9, 1) < range3 ) = 20;
```

And now let's do it step by step

You are conditioning on the last three elements `B( 7:9, 1 )` which are `-3, -6` and `-9`.
Therefore you end up with

```
>> B(7:9, 1) < range3
ans = 
  true
  true 
  true
```

You have a logical indexing of **three** elements. Using these logical indices to access `B`, which has **9** elements result with an access to the **first three elements out of nine**.
Thus, all your commands only modifes the first three elements of `B` without affecting the rest of `B`.

#### A possible fix:

You can actively define the range you are working on, for example, the second column:

```
>> aRange = 4:6;
>> B( aRange( B(aRange, 1) > range2 ) ) = 0
```

See how the three-vector logical indexing `B(aRange, 1) > range2 )` now index `aRange` (which has 3 elements) and not `B` (which has 9 elements) directly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understood that too but could you tell me how I can modify my code such that correct elements of the matrix are getting accessed. I mean should I pad zeros or something to another matrix and then apply this indexing operation ?

Comment: Yes I did see your edit now. Thanks for the answer. It works perfectly.

Comment: Hi again. Can this be performed using the bsxfun function? Question continued from : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18201729/forcing-the-columns-of-a-matrix-within-different-limits

Comment: since you already "flatten" `B` into a vecotr, I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
A=[-1,2,-3;-4,5,-6;-7,8,-9];
range1 = 0;range2 = -5;range3 = 0;
B=A;
B((B(:,1)<range1),1)=10;
B((B(:,2)>range2),2)=0;
B((B(:,3)<range3),3)=20;
```

Output B is in mxn dimension as your A.

If you want it as column vector.

```
B=B(:);
```

Comment: Thanks this works too. But as I stated before I want the operation to do on the matrix B and not on the matrix A. The column matrix has already been formed.

Comment: Well, just in case if you want to use mxn matrix you can ignore last line. And, the operation is done on matrix B only ;)

Comment: Hi again. Can this be performed using the bsxfun function? Question continued from : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18201729/forcing-the-columns-of-a-matrix-within-different-limits