# performance difference between subscript indexing and linear indexing

Tags: matlab, indexing

I have a 2D matrix in MATLAB and I use two different ways to access its elements. One is based on subscript indexing and the other is based on linear indexing. I test both methods by following code:

```
N = 512; it = 400; im = zeros(N);
%// linear indexing
[ind_x,ind_y] = ndgrid(1:2:N,1:2:N);
index = sub2ind(size(im),ind_x,ind_y);

tic
for i=1:it
    im(index) = im(index) + 1;
end
toc %//cost 0.45 seconds on my machine (MATLAB2015b, Thinkpad T410)

%// subscript indexing
x = 1:2:N;
y = 1:2:N;

tic
for i=1:it
    im(x,y) = im(x,y) +1;
end
toc %// cost 0.12 seconds on my machine(MATLAB2015b, Thinkpad T410)

%//someone pointed that double or uint32 might an issue, so we turn both into uint32

%//uint32 for linear indexing
index = uint32(index);
tic
for i=1:it
    im(index) = im(index) +1;
end
toc%// cost 0.25 seconds on my machine(MATLAB2015b, Thinkpad T410)

%//uint32 for the subscript indexing
x = uint32(1:2:N);
y = uint32(1:2:N);
tic
for i=1:it
    im(x,y) = im(x,y) +1;
end
toc%// cost 0.11 seconds on my machine(MATLAB2015b, Thinkpad T410)

%% /*********************comparison with others*****************/
%//third way of indexing, loops
tic
for i=1:it
    for j=1:2:N
        for k=1:2:N
            im(j,k) = im(j,k)+1;
        end
    end
end
toc%// cost 0.74 seconds on my machine(MATLAB2015b, Thinkpad T410)
```

It seems that directly using subscript indexing is faster than the linear indexing obtained from `sub2ind`. Does anyone know why? I thought they were almost the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is indexing vectors in MATLAB inefficient?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382155/is-indexing-vectors-in-matlab-inefficient)

Comment: And the [linked MATLAB Central thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/54522-why-is-indexing-vectors-matrices-in-matlab-very-inefficient)

Comment: `sub2ind` has some overhead. Try its "manual" version `index = bsxfun(@plus, (1:2:size(im,1)).', ((1:2:size(im,2))-1)*size(im,1))`. Also, better use [`timeit`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html) for the timing rather than `tic`/`toc`

Comment: Whoops, now I see the overhead I referred to is outside your timing

Comment: @Luis, I didn't count the time for sub2ind. Just two ways of accessing the elements in the matrix.

Comment: My first thought is that [`subsref`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subsref.html) has to do more internal work in order to generate the index tuples from the linear indexes since the array is actually indexed that way either as a native array or some data structure (i.e., I think linear indexes/arrays are syntactic sugar).

Comment: @TroyHaskin as far as I understand, in MATLAB subscript indexes are the syntactic sugar. MATLAB stores all higher dimensional matrices as linear arrays internally (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/memory-allocation.html?refresh=true#brh72ex-5)

Comment: @Dan, yes, I think Matlab has the linear storage. That is why this code confuses me. In the linear case, the linear index should be faster than subscript fashion. But the results show the other way around.

Comment: @Dan You are, of course, [correct](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511). I was writing off the cuff without thinking. So I'll revise my statement to: `subsref`, or whatever mechanism the JIT resolves indexing to, is optimized for index tuples instead of linear indexes.

Comment: For linear indexing, MATLAB has to read the 65'536 values from `index`. Using subscripts only needs 2*256 = 512 values from `x` and `y`. Could this be a reason? Does anybody have a clue how to test this?

Comment: @hbaderts, it should not be the reason. Even we have 2*256 index for row and column, we still need to access the same number of elements.

Comment: As I am saying in my answer that should be the reason. Linear indices are stored in RAM and accessing(reading) them is costlier than doing a double loop over the pair of subscripts.

Comment: What is you processor? Can you try to use a in32 instead of double for the index? as  hbaderts pointes out, your index array has 64kentries - 512kB, and your data itself has 4MB (2MB active in the cache).  depending on your cache size 512kB extra could make the difference between everything in the cache and accessing RAM contineously (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34831118/speed-up-reshape-not-use-reshape-matlab/34831498#34831498) - typical perfpormance jumps are ~ factor of 3-4.

Answer (score 8):

## The intuition

As Daniel mentioned in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34789654/2180721), the linear index takes up more space in RAM while the subscripts are much smaller.

For the subscripted indexing, internally, Matlab will not create the linear index, but it will use a (double) *compiled* loop to cycle through all elements.

The subscripted version on the other hand will have to loop through all the linear indices *passed from outside*, which will require more reads from memory, thus will take longer.

## Claims

- Linear indexing is faster
- ...as long as the total number of indices is the same

## Timings

From the timings we see a direct confirmation for the first claim and we can infer the second with some additional testing (below).

```
LOOPED
      subs assignment: 0.2878s
    linear assignment: 0.0812s

VECTORIZED
      subs assignment: 0.0302s
    linear assignment: 0.0862s
```

## First claim

We can test it with loops. The number of `subref` operations is the **same** but the linear index points directly to the element of interest while subscripts, internally, need to be converted.

The functions of interest:

```
function B = subscriptedIndexing(A,row,col)
n = numel(row);
B = zeros(n);
for r = 1:n
    for c = 1:n
        B(r,c) = A(row(r),col(c));
    end
end
end

function B = linearIndexing(A,index)
B = zeros(size(index));
for ii = 1:numel(index)
    B(ii) = A(index(ii));
end
end
```

## Second claim

This claim is an inference from the observed difference in speed when using the vectorized approach.

First, the vectorized approach (as opposed to the looped) speeds up the subscripted assignment while linear indexing is slightly slower (probably not statistically significant).

Second, the only difference in the two indexing methods comes from the size of the indices/subscripts. We want to isolate this as the only possible cause of the difference in the timings. One other major player could be JIT optimization.

The testing functions:

```
function B = subscriptedIndexingVect(A,row,col)
n = numel(row);
B = zeros(n);
B = A(row,col);
end

function B = linearIndexingVect(A,index)
B = zeros(size(index));
B = A(index);
end
```

***NOTE**: I keep the superfluous preallocation of `B`, to keep the vectorized and looped approaches comparable. In other words, differences in timings should only come from indexing and the internal implementation of the loops.*

All tests are run with:

```
function testFun(N)
A             = magic(N);
row           = 1:2:N;
col           = 1:2:N;
[ind_x,ind_y] = ndgrid(row,col);
index         = sub2ind(size(A),ind_x,ind_y);

% isequal(linearIndexing(A,index), subscriptedIndexing(A,row,col))
% isequal(linearIndexingVect(A,index), subscriptedIndexingVect(A,row,col))

fprintf('<strong>LOOPED</strong>\n')
fprintf('      subs assignment: %.4fs\n',  timeit(@()subscriptedIndexing(A,row,col)))
fprintf('    linear assignment: %.4fs\n\n',timeit(@()linearIndexing(A,index)))
fprintf('<strong>VECTORIZED</strong>\n')
fprintf('      subs assignment: %.4fs\n',  timeit(@()subscriptedIndexingVect(A,row,col)))
fprintf('    linear assignment: %.4fs\n',  timeit(@()linearIndexingVect(A,index)))
end
```

Turning JIT on/off has **NO** impact:

```
feature accel off
testFun(5e3)
...

VECTORIZED
      subs assignment: 0.0303s
    linear assignment: 0.0873s

feature accel on
testFun(5e3)
...

VECTORIZED
      subs assignment: 0.0303s
    linear assignment: 0.0871s
```

This **excludes** that subscripted assignment's superior speed comes from JIT optimization which leaves us with the only plausible cause, **number of RAM accesses**. It is true that the final matrix has the same number of elements. However, the linear assignment has to retrieve all elements of the index in order to fetch the numbers.

## SETUP

Tested on Win7 64 with MATLAB R2015b. Prior versions of Matlab will provide different results due to recent changes in [Matlab's execution engine](http://uk.mathworks.com/products/matlab/matlab-execution-engine/)

In fact, turning JIT off in Matlab **R2014a** affects timings, but only for the loops (expected result):

```
feature accel off
testFun(5e3)

LOOPED
      subs assignment: 7.8915s
    linear assignment: 6.4418s

VECTORIZED
      subs assignment: 0.0295s
    linear assignment: 0.0878s
```

This again confirms that the difference in timings between linear and sibscripted assignment should come from the number of RAM accesses, since JIT does not play a role in the vectorized approach.

Answer (score 4):

It does not really surprise me that the subscript indexing is much faster here. If you take a look at your input data, the index is much smaller in this case. For the subscript indexing case you have 512 elements while for the linear indexing case you have 65536 elements.

When you apply your example to a vector instead, you will notice that there is no difference between both methods.

Here is the slightly modified code I used to evaluate different matrix sizes:

```
it = 400; im = zeros(512*512,1);
x = 1:2:size(im,1);
y = 1:2:size(im,2);
%// linear indexing
[ind_x,ind_y] = ndgrid(x,y);
index = sub2ind(size(im),ind_x,ind_y);

tic
for i=1:it
    im(index) = im(index) + 1;
end
toc 

%// subscript indexing


tic
for i=1:it
    im(x,y) = im(x,y) +1;
end
toc
```

Comment: What do you mean to a vector instead? I tried the same thing with nested loops and got the same performance characteristics?

Comment: @Dan: I added the code. As it is it creates a vector. Change the `zeros(512*512,1)` to `zeros(512*512,3)` and you will notice that the linear indexing version roughly doubles in time and index size, while the subscript indexing version is only slightly slower.

Comment: @Daniel, the two fashion should access the same number of elements. No? Otherwise, they are different in function. Then, it does not make sense to compare these two. In my code, they do exactly the same work and access the same number of elements, but with different running time.

Comment: They are accessing the same number of elements, the size of the indexed area is the same, but the index itself differs in size.

Comment: @Daniel but does this apply to my (now deleted by a moderator) example using for loops and accessing a single element at a time? In that case the size of the indexed area is never greater than 1 element.

Comment: @Dan: For your example I got only a minor speed difference between 10% and 25%. Not sure what happened.

Comment: @Daniel I'm running 2015a, could be a version thing. But I then replaced the inner lines of my loops with `im(1,1);`  (instead of `im(r,c) = im(r,c) +1;`) and `im(1);` (instead of `im(ind) = im(ind) + 1;`) and I still get an almost 50% for subscript (0.84s) indexing over linear indexing (1.42s)!

Comment: And I'm get the same speeds when I make `im = zeros(N^2,1)` (for the code mention in my previous comment)

Answer (score 0):

A very good question. Right ahead, I don't know the correct answer, however, you can analyze the behavior. Save the first toc into t1 and the second one into t2. At the end calculate `t1/t2`. You will recognize, changing the number of iterations or the size of your matrix does (almost) not change the factor. 
I propose:

- The amount of iterations only improves the quality of the tictoc. (obvious?)
- The size of the matrix has no influcence, i.e. there must be a time delay in the syntax.

I imagine, that there is simply an internal check or transformation from linear index to subscript indexing, i.e. the internal addition (operation) you perform is exactly the same. It appears to be more natural to use subscript indexing instead of linear indexing, so maybe mathworks simply optimized the first.

**UPDATE**:
You can also simply access an element in your matrix, you will see, that using subscript index is faster than using linear index. That supports the theory, that there is a *slow* conversion done internally from linear to subscript.

Comment: I add the third way of indexing using the subscript directly access one element in the matrix. It is the slowest in the three methods. I guess it does not use the vectorization in matlab, so it is slow.

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER: I don't have a MATLAB license at the moment, so the code I provide below is admittedly untested. However, if anyone decides to test, please comment on this answer accordingly.

Depending on your release of MATLAB (are you using R2015b?), there is a possibility that you may not have paid the full upfront cost of preallocation when invoking "zeros". There is a possibility that you are paying for allocation on the first get/set of **im**, which is causing additional but hidden overhead when you first access the values inside **im**.

See: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/preallocation-performance

As an initial test, I suggest switching the order that you are profiling the code:

```
N = 512; it = 400; im = zeros(N);

%// subscript indexing
x = 1:2:N;
y = 1:2:N;

tic
for i=1:it
    im(x,y) = im(x,y) +1;
end
toc %// What's the cost now?

%// linear indexing
[ind_x,ind_y] = ndgrid(1:2:N,1:2:N);
index = sub2ind(size(im),ind_x,ind_y);

tic
for i=1:it
    im(index) = im(index) + 1;
end
toc %// What's the cost now?
```

To profile perhaps more fairly against subscript vs. linear indexing, I suggest one of two possible methods:

1. Make sure you incur allocation costs on both methods by creating two separate im matrices, **im1** and **im2**, both initially set to zeros(N), and use each matrix for a separate indexing method.
2. Run a full get/set on each element of im before actually profiling between subscript vs. linear indexing.

Method 1:

```
N = 512; it = 400; im1 = zeros(N); im2 = zeros(N);

%// subscript indexing
x = 1:2:N;
y = 1:2:N;

tic
for i=1:it
    im1(x,y) = im1(x,y) + 1;
end
toc %// What's the cost now?

%// linear indexing
[ind_x,ind_y] = ndgrid(1:2:N,1:2:N);
index = sub2ind(size(im2),ind_x,ind_y);

tic
for i=1:it
    im2(index) = im2(index) + 1;
end
toc %// What's the cost now?
```

Method 2:

```
N = 512; it = 400; im = zeros(N);

%// Run a full get/set on each element to force allocation
tic
for i=1:N^2
    im(i) = im(i) +1;
end
toc 


%// subscript indexing
x = 1:2:N;
y = 1:2:N;

tic
for i=1:it
    im(x,y) = im(x,y) +1;
end
toc %// What's the cost now?

%// linear indexing
[ind_x,ind_y] = ndgrid(1:2:N,1:2:N);
index = sub2ind(size(im),ind_x,ind_y);

tic
for i=1:it
    im(index) = im(index) + 1;
end
toc %// What's the cost now?
```

I have a second hypothesis, which is that you incur some additional overhead when you explicitly declare each and every single element to be accessed, versus if you have MATLAB infer the elements for you. excasa's ["duplicate post" reference](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/54522-why-is-indexing-vectors-matrices-in-matlab-very-inefficient) (not exactly a duplicate in my humble opinion) has the same general insight, but uses different datapoints to come to this conclusion. I won't write examples of this here, but basically, creating a straight up giant array **index** compared to the smaller subscript indices **x** and **y** gives MATLAB less room for internal optimizations. I don't know what inside MATLAB would perform these specific optimizations, but perhaps they come from the black magic that you may know as [MATLAB's JIT/LXE](http://www.matlabtips.com/matlab-is-no-longer-slow-at-for-loops/). If you honestly want to check if JIT is the culprit here (and are working in 2014b or prior), then you can try disabling it and then running the code above.

There are several ways to disable the JIT:

1. Use [undocumented feature methods](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/87225).
2. Copy/paste the commands to the command prompt, as opposed running them straight from the script editor.

Unfortunately, I do not know of a way to turn of LXE in R2015a and later, and trying to diagnose if LXE is the culprit may be a bit of an uphill battle. If this is where you are stuck, perhaps you can delve even further via [MathWorks' technical support](http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us) or [MathWorks Central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/index). You may be surprised to find some astounding experts from either source.

Comment: Ran all your code snippets, subscript indexing is still much faster than linear indexing (in all your cases). Also, I tried this using for loops so indexing with a scalar each time and subscript indexing is still faster.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for testing the snippets. Out of curiosity, did you also try disabling/re-enabling JIT?

Comment: I did not try disabling the JIT