# Speed up reshape/ not use reshape Matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, reshape

I have this operation which is called multiple times:

```
longRowVector;
matrix = reshape(longRowVector, n, n)';
answer = matrix(:);
```

This operation using reshape is slow. Is there a way to get to answer without using reshape.

Comment: I tried pre-computing a permutation vector, then directly use `answer=longRowVector(p)` but only that single line is slower than your code. Also reading [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34831498/2732801) I think there is nothing to optimize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way to speed that up. if n exceeds a certain number (defined by your relevant cache size), the way in which the memory accesses will be ordered during the transpose operator. The cost is actually create in the transpose operation. Below i plot this cost for different matrix sizes. There is a jump at around 360, which is consistent with the cache size on my processor.

If you want to avoid this hit, then you need to create your "cache-optimized" reordering strategy, i.e. perform the reordering in m*m tiles where both of the vectors will fit in the cache.

[image: Cost (arb) of transposition versus matrix size]

Comment: remark: reshape is basically a zero-cost operation, as long as you don't write to the result....

Comment: Do you see any possibility to identify such blocks? I think it's impossible because each of the (n-1) neighbours to each side in the input list has a distance of at least n in the output matrix. Probably the reason why transposing a matrix is expensive in runtime.

Comment: I was afraid this was the case! thanks for the answer!

Comment: Yes, i think computing the blocks is not difficult, but i would have to test how well that really works. I think that subdividing in m * m blocks (m  * m * 8<cachesize/2) should work. Will try sometimes soon

Comment: Tested it, and as far as i can see - no significant difference (which indicates that the transpose operator already does it as good as possible)